# In which version was this syntactic feature added to ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was maintaining a ruby gem and it works fine with the latest ruby version on my machine. Recently, a user reported that a syntax feature doesn't work with his `ruby-2.0.0`.

I meant to update the required version of ruby for this gem, so I intend to find out the least version that supports all the features.

The feature that is incompatible with `2.0.0` is something like:

```
def my_method(*args, added_param:, &block)
   ...
   super(*args, &block)
end
```

which I use to add a specific parameter to a method when this module is prepended to some class.

I checked ruby change log, but still don't know which update this one is referring to.

Comment: *Which* 'feature'? If you don't know the name, at least describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to named arguments (`added_param:`), it was added in 2.1, I looked for that feature too, some time ago.

Comment: To clarify: *optional* keyword parameters with default arguments were added in 2.0, *mandatory* keyword parameters were added in 2.1.